# AstroJS hybrid mode server endpoint returns 404

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, astrojs

I have an AstroJS project here is my `astro.config.mjs`:

```js
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";
import vue from '@astrojs/vue';
import sanity from "@sanity/astro";
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import { sanityClientConfigWithCdn } from './const';
import node from '@astrojs/node';

export default defineConfig({
  output: 'hybrid',
  adapter: node({
    mode: 'standalone',
  }),
  integrations: [
    tailwind(), 
    sanity(sanityClientConfigWithCdn), 
    vue({appEntrypoint: "/src/vue.ts"}),
  ]
});
```

Here is my test API endpoint:

```js
import type { APIRoute } from "astro";

export const prerender = false;

export const GET: APIRoute = async ({ params, request }) => {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({
    message: "TEST"
  }))
}
```

And finally here my pages file structure:

```
├── api
│   └── test.ts
└── [...lang]
    ├── index.astro
    └── news.astro
```

I am getting this error/warning:

```
06:49:15 PM [getStaticPaths] A `getStaticPaths()` route pattern was matched, but no matching static path was found for requested path `/404`.

Possible dynamic routes being matched: src/pages/[...lang]/index.astro.
06:49:15 PM [serve]    404                                     /404
```

At first I was thinking that the `[...lang]` dynamic route was the problem. However, I am still getting 404 even after deleting the whole directory. I am executing `npm run dev` and trying to access http://localhost:3000/api/test (that is the correct host and port). What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your development server? Which version of Astro are you using?

Comment: I am stuck with an older Astro version (2.10.1) because I'm going to production by the of the month. I was thinking of upgrading after this release. I understand that this could be the problem but doesn't Astro 2 support hybrid rendering, as well. I also tried with `output: server` resulting into the same problem. I will try with Astro latest in a feature branch to see if it gets resolved.

Comment: @cgeopapa In what file do you have your "test API endpoint"? At least in newer Astro versions, you need to put it e.g. `src/pages/api/test.json.ts` for http://localhost:3000/api/test to work (note the `pages` and `.json.` parts that you seem to be missing.)

Comment: The tree path I have in my question is the file structure inside the `pages` directory. Although, I am missing the `.json.` part, I'll try that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I indeed had to upgrade my AstroJS version. A side-effect of using an outdated AstroJS version was that I was installing an outdated of `@astrojs/node` so probably this was causing a problem, as well. So same file structure, same code, same everything except from the Astro version and it now works as expected.